# Installing Ubuntu from Live iso to hard drive

Tags: boot, hard-drive, live-usb

I am trying to image 75 acer aspire's for the school I work for with Ubuntu 14.04 - it needed a couple extras like chrome and our wireless configuration for example.

I created a live boot using systemback and can boot into the image on another laptop but only from the flash drive. I obviously can't leave a flash drive in 75 laptops for third graders :) .  I can't find the installer as someone had pointed out on another forum I investigated.

How do I install the iso image onto the hard drives of the other laptops?

Comment: So, what's the problem? You have a live USB already created now,  boot into it (you may have to change the boot order in BIOS) and when the options comes, select install Ubuntu and follow the on-screen instructions.

Comment: Thats the issue, it never gives me the option to install it. It literally just starts up into my desktop on Ubuntu.   I don't have the "try or install" option.

Is there a way to force it to install from the terminal?

Comment: Can't you see an 'install Ubuntu' icon on the desktop?

Comment: Nope, there is nothing on the desktop. 

I boot to USB, The Systemback Live screen appears, I select "Boot Live System", goes right to purple Ubuntu loading screen, log in screen, blank desktop. 

It nevers gives the option to install like it would with a fresh iso. But I had read that it is supposed to leave an install icon on the desktop, although it does not - I assume because this is an exact image of the original laptop.

So that is where I am confused. I assumed there would be a way in the terminal, but can't find it anywhere.  Is there an issue with my image/bootable?

Comment: It doesn't give me the option to start systemback from the live usb....I have a live usb of systemback though, should I put them both in and boot from the usb with systemback?   and try to do it that way?


When I boot into Ubuntu the systemback  program is there, but all it lets me do is view the partitions. I can't find an option to write to one or install or anything like that

Comment: what I meant was boot from systemback live usb which contains image of your os and see if you can access start systemback application from it.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that:

Download `Clonezilla live`, select the following CPU architecture and file type.

[Clonezilla site download](http://clonezilla.org/downloads/download.php?branch=alternative)

Install `Tuxboot` to copy `Clonezilla` to a `USB stick.`

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tuxboot
```

Once you get `Tuxboot` installed, use it to create your  live bootable `Clonezilla USB stick`.

First create a `FAT32` partition of at least 400 megabytes.

Then run `Tuxboot`, check `Pre-downloaded` and click the button with the ellipsis to select your `Clonezilla` file.

Boot up your `Clonezilla` USB stick on the computer that you want to backup,  at the Start Clonezilla menu select `Start Clonezilla`.

In the next menu select `device_image`, then go to the next screen.

This is where you select the location for your `backup image` to be copied to.

An attached USB hard drive is a nice fast and easy option.

In the next screen you can choose `savedisk`, which creates an image of an entire hard disk, or `save_parts`.

After making your selections, the next screen gives you the option to do a filesystem check and repair.

Restoring your image is similar to creating it.

Again, boot up `Clonezilla`, go through the same initial steps, select `dev_image`, and then on the local_dev screen select the `location` of your image that you want to restore, whether it's on a `local device` or `network share`.

[Source](http://clonezilla.org/clonezilla-live-doc.php)